# How to implement databinding for windows custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Basically, I am confused about how to implement databinding on the control side.

I am trying to write a custom list control in C#, which implements databinding.  I want it to end up having similar functionality to the ListView, but with an interface similar to ListBox.

I have a private nested class called "ListRow" which handles rendering of each row.  There is an internal binding source which gets changes from the data and causes the control to invalidate if necessary.  The problem now is that I want to add a checkbox to the ListRow, and I am not sure the best way to implement it so that the underlying object's property gets changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to follow this example.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataBindCustomControls.aspx

Comment: Thanks that article was very helpful.  I have been looking for an explanation like that for a while